# Ember CLI ember new and ember init files not showing but buildable

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ember-cli, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm using ember v1.13.15, node: 5.4.1, npm 2.14.10 and os linux x64 (ubuntu). I'm actually trying to get ember-cli into my rails app. When executing `ember new frontend` I get the output that a bunch of files were created. These files don't show up in nautilus, terminal via ls nor can I cd into the directory. I manually typed `mkdir frontend && cd frontend` then `ember init` with the same results. If I run `ember init` again it recognizes the files are there because it asks me if I want to overwrite some files.

Running `ember build` produces a successful build, but where are the files?

**Updated with terminal**

```
uhoh@eblinux:~/Documents/apps/mvp$ cd frontendconsumer/
uhoh@eblinux:~/Documents/apps/mvp/frontendconsumer$ ls
uhoh@eblinux:~/Documents/apps/mvp/frontendconsumer$ ember init
version: 1.13.15
Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
installing app
  identical .bowerrc
  identical .editorconfig
  identical .ember-cli
  identical .jshintrc
  identical .travis.yml
  identical .watchmanconfig
  identical README.md
  identical app/app.js
  identical app/index.html
  identical app/router.js
  identical app/templates/application.hbs
  identical bower.json
  identical config/environment.js
  identical ember-cli-build.js
  identical .gitignore
  identical package.json
  identical public/crossdomain.xml
  identical public/robots.txt
  identical testem.json
  identical tests/.jshintrc
  identical tests/helpers/destroy-app.js
  identical tests/helpers/module-for-acceptance.js
  identical tests/helpers/resolver.js
  identical tests/helpers/start-app.js
  identical tests/index.html
  identical tests/test-helper.js
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Installed browser packages via Bower.
uhoh@eblinux:~/Documents/apps/mvp/frontendconsumer$ ls
uhoh@eblinux:~/Documents/apps/mvp/frontendconsumer$ ls -a
. ..
```

**Update v2**

```
    uhoh@eblinux:~/Documents/apps/mvp/frontendconsumer$ locate test-helper.js --all
    /home/uhoh/Documents/apps/integration/node_modules/jshint/node_modules/htmlparser2/test/test-helper.js
    /home/uhoh/Documents/apps/newapp/node_modules/jshint/node_modules/htmlparser2/test/test-helper.js
    /home/uhoh/Documents/apps/vd-integrations/test/test-helper.js
    /home/uhoh/Downloads/ace1.3.1/mustache/js/node_modules/htmlparser2/tests/test-helper.js
    /home/uhoh/Downloads/ace1_3.0/mustache/js/node_modules/htmlparser2/tests/test-helper.js
/home/uhoh/Downloads/ace3/mustache/js/node_modules/htmlparser2/tests/test-helper.js
/home/uhoh/consumer_frontend/node_modules/ember-cli/blueprints/app/files/tests/test-helper.js
/home/uhoh/consumer_frontend/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/tests/test-helper.js
/home/uhoh/consumer_frontend/node_modules/ember-cli-content-security-policy/tests/test-helper.js
/home/uhoh/consumer_frontend/node_modules/ember-cli-qunit/node_modules/broccoli-jshint/node_modules/jshint/node_modules/htmlparser2/test/test-helper.js
```

Comment: wow this is quite strange, we have seen some race conditions with process.chdir in node. Its possible this is related?

Instead of using nautilus, what does `ls` int he command line say?

Comment: thanks @StefanPenner - I updated with the terminal output. any insights would be great. It's on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to comment, so instead I will offer you two main options:

- Uninstall all ember related packages and push node to 5.6.0 and npm to 3.6.0 (the version that I using.)

  1. `npm uninstall -g ember-cli`
  2. `sudo npm cache clean -f`
  3. `sudo npm install -g n`
  4. `sudo n stable`
  5. Install Ember and the needed packages, confirm version of node and npm and try to create the project.
- Probe the files on the frontendconsumer folder:

  1. Type`sync`and see if something shows up on Nautilus.
  2. Use `locate test-helper.js -c` or locate any other file that was supposed to be there. If the result is 0 then give the other locate [params](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/mlocate.1.html) a try.
  3. Type `baobab` and see if something shows up on the folder.
  4. If nothing yet, then try `find -type l` to see if there are any symbolic links.
  5. Run a [checkdisk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59064/how-to-run-a-checkdisk) on your hard drive.

If none of those options helped, then something really weird is going when scaffolding the new application... If there is no other issues on your system, try to create a rails app through [RVM](https://rvm.io/) to see if the scaffold of a new app works out. If it does, then chances are that something within npm, node or the ember packages are bad. Otherwise, it may be your system.

Comment: Thanks @deovandski, I ran through everything and it found the test-helper.js file. Finally went back to it and ran `locate test-helper.js -A` which lists all files. This might just be a RTFM moment on my part then, but I'd expect ember init to create the files in the current directory, but it seems it was built in the root of the user directory. Is there anywhere to change this, as I need the files to be created in my project directory so I can package it up with my Rails app.

Comment: The **output v2** that you placed mostly pertain to some globals installed around like `npm install -g ember-cli`, so let's try out a different path: create a new folder on your home and run `ember new testApp -v |& tee ~/testAppVerboseLog.txt` inside it. This command will create a new ember App while outputting a verbose log of everything that is happening into testAppVerboseLog.txt. The file will be saved to home, so make it available for me to see. Whatever is happening, the verbose log will show it...

Comment: Hey @Michael did you ever resolve this so that it sent it to your current directory instead of your home directory? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Hey @John, can you follow the command on my previous comment and post a link to it here? Perhaps the root cause is the same...

Comment: The verbose contains some notices like "correctMkdir not in flight; initializing" which could mean that the problem is network related (NPM Issue #11361), leftover files like package.json (Ember Cli Issue #2718) or NPM related (NPM Pull #11142.) Can you attempt to verbose again on a new network or use another machine on the same network? If the issue happens again on a new network or if the other machine installs fine on the same network, can you obliterate NPM and any leftover package.json file on AppData\Roaming\npm-cache, your home folder and testApp?